# Linker error, when archiving project with Xcode 8.3.2

Tags: xcode, linker, promisekit, xcode8

After updating to Xcode 8.3.2 from Xcode 8.0 I started seeing this Linker error, when **Archiving** my project:

[image: Linker error]

However, the project compiles still **Runs** with **Debug** configuration correctly.

That makes me think that the problem might have something to do with my headers configuration (Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags).

I am using PromiseKit 3.5.1.

Debug headers:

[image: Headers for Release]

Release headers:

[image: Headers for debug]

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you figure it out?